# Adding a list of objects to SQL Server - ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to add a list of objects to a SQL Server database via Entity Framework but I get an error with Add

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post(List<Row> rows)
{
    try
    {
        using (DbModel dbModel = new DbModel())
        {
            foreach (var el in rows)
            {
                dbModel.Provider_Status.Add(el);
            }

            dbModel.SaveChanges();
        }
    } 
    catch { }
}
```

Row class:

```
public class Row
{
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileTitle { get; set; }
    public string ProviderID { get; set; }
    public string ServiceID { get; set; }
    public string PublishDate { get; set; }
    public string ExpiryDate { get; set; }
}
```

Database Model DbModel:

```
    public partial class Provider_Status
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string FileTitle { get; set; }
        public string ProviderID { get; set; }
        public string ServiceID { get; set; }
        public string PublishDate { get; set; }
        public string ExpiryDate { get; set; }
    }
```

Error Message:

> CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'File_Upload.Models.Row' to 'File_Upload.Models.Provider_Status

Comment: What is the error?? And what does your `DbModel` class look like?

Comment: I updated the post which have the DbModel and the error message

Comment: Maybe you need a type convertor from Row to Provider_Status, because it looks like you're trying to insert Row objects into the Provider_Status collection.

Comment: I changed the parameter to  List<Provider_Status> rows and it worked .. Thank you guys

Comment: Also take a look at AddRange instead of using a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DbModel` defines a data set of type `Provider_Status` - so if you want to add data to this data set, you need to provide `Provider_Status` objects - not `Row` objects (as you do now).

You need to convert those `Row` object to `Provider_Status` - try something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post(List<Row> rows)
{
    try
    {
        using (DbModel dbModel = new DbModel())
        {
            foreach (var el in rows)
            {
                // create a new "Provider_Status" object, based on the
                // "Row" values being passed in
                Provider_Status status = new Provider_Status
                                         {
                                            FileName    = el.FileName 
                                            FileTitle   = el.FileTitle 
                                            ProviderID  = el.ProviderID
                                            ServiceID   = el.ServiceID 
                                            PublishDate = el.PublishDate
                                            ExpiryDate  = el.ExpiryDate
                                         };

                // add that new Provider_Status object to your dbModel
                dbModel.Provider_Status.Add(status);
            }

            dbModel.SaveChanges();
        }
    } 
    catch { }
}
```